# C# dbf - xml - sql

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, dbf

Задача грузить dbf в sql. Прямого рабочего способа не нашел, подумал что можно перекодировать dbf в xml, а дальше уже работа с ним проблем не составляет. Проблема возникла на этапе чтения dbf, в основном все нормально, но есть файлы (cod. 866) в которых сбивается кодировка.

Читаю так. Работать с провайдерами MS не получается. пишет "не найден устанавливаемый ISAM", MS OF 2010 x32. Есть ли решения проблемы? Перелопатил массу форумов и перепробовал что можно.

```
var connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1; Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties=dBASE IV; Collating Sequence=machine;";
// @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\\;
var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), con);
con.Close();
var dataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
dataGrid.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Кодировка dbf - указывается в одном из байтов шапки. Касательно JET - оно берёт файл используя настройку кодировки из системного реестра. Думаю лучше взять самописный импорт из DBF, желательно что б он учитывал значение байта кодировки, или делал автодетект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помог OleDB @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:*cat*;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;"; хорошо и без проблем читает файлы формата 8.3

Answer (score 1):

В свое время понадобилось экспортировать кучу файлов dbf.
Нашел вот такой класс (источник уж и не помню где взял) (**код в конце вопроса**).

по сути использование:

```
DataTable table=ParseDBF.ReadDBF(fileName);
```

в большинстве случаев нормально читало и cp866 и cp1251.

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

// Read an entire standard DBF file into a DataTable
public class ParseDBF
{
    // This is the file header for a DBF. We do this special layout with everything
    // packed so we can read straight from disk into the structure to populate it
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    private struct DBFHeader
    {
        public byte version;
        public byte updateYear;
        public byte updateMonth;
        public byte updateDay;
        public Int32 numRecords;
        public Int16 headerLen;
        public Int16 recordLen;
        public Int16 reserved1;
        public byte incompleteTrans;
        public byte encryptionFlag;
        public Int32 reserved2;
        public Int64 reserved3;
        public byte MDX;
        public byte language;
        public Int16 reserved4;
    }

    // This is the field descriptor structure. There will be one of these for each column in the table.
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    private struct FieldDescriptor
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string fieldName;
        public char fieldType;
        public Int32 address;
        public byte fieldLen;
        public byte count;
        public Int16 reserved1;
        public byte workArea;
        public Int16 reserved2;
        public byte flag;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]
        public byte[] reserved3;
        public byte indexFlag;
    }

    public static string ConvertString(string value, Encoding src, Encoding trg)
    {
        Decoder dec = src.GetDecoder();
        byte[] ba = trg.GetBytes(value);
        int len = dec.GetCharCount(ba, 0, ba.Length);
        char[] ca = new char[len];
        dec.GetChars(ba, 0, ba.Length, ca, 0);
        return new string(ca);
    }
    public static string ConvertString(byte[] value, Encoding src, Encoding trg)
    {
        Decoder dec = src.GetDecoder();
        byte[] ba = value;
        int len = dec.GetCharCount(ba, 0, ba.Length);
        char[] ca = new char[len];
        dec.GetChars(ba, 0, ba.Length, ca, 0);
        return new string(ca);
    }

    // Read an entire standard DBF file into a DataTable
    public static DataTable ReadDBF(string dbfFile)
    {
        long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        BinaryReader recReader;
        string number;
        string year;
        string month;
        string day;
        long lDate;
        long lTime;
        DataRow row;
        int fieldIndex;

        // If there isn't even a file, just return an empty DataTable
        if ((false == File.Exists(dbfFile)))
        {
            return dt;
        }

        BinaryReader br = null;
        try
        {
            // Read the header into a buffer
            br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(dbfFile));
            byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DBFHeader)));

            // Marshall the header into a DBFHeader structure
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            DBFHeader header = (DBFHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(DBFHeader));
            handle.Free();

            // Read in all the field descriptors. Per the spec, 13 (0D) marks the end of the field descriptors
            ArrayList fields = new ArrayList();
            while ((13 != br.PeekChar()))
            {
                buffer = br.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FieldDescriptor)));
                handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                fields.Add((FieldDescriptor)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(FieldDescriptor)));
                handle.Free();
            }

            // Read in the first row of records, we need this to help determine column types below
            ((FileStream)br.BaseStream).Seek(header.headerLen + 1, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            buffer = br.ReadBytes(header.recordLen);
            recReader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(buffer));

            // Create the columns in our new DataTable
            DataColumn col = null;
            foreach (FieldDescriptor field in fields)
            {
                number = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recReader.ReadBytes(field.fieldLen));
                switch (field.fieldType)
                {
                    case 'N':
                        if (number.IndexOf(".") > -1)
                        {
                            col = new DataColumn(field.fieldName, typeof(decimal));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            col = new DataColumn(field.fieldName, typeof(int));
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        col = new DataColumn(field.fieldName, typeof(string));
                        break;
                    case 'T':
                        // You can uncomment this to see the time component in the grid
                        //col = new DataColumn(field.fieldName, typeof(string));
                        col = new DataColumn(field.fieldName, typeof(DateTime));
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        col = new DataColumn(field.fieldName, typeof(DateTime));
                        break;
                    case 'L':
                        col = new DataColumn(field.fieldName, typeof(bool));
                        break;
                    case 'F':
                        col = new DataColumn(field.fieldName, typeof(Double));
                        break;
                    case '0':
                        col = null;
                        break;
                }
                if (col!=null)
                    dt.Columns.Add(col);
            }

            // Skip past the end of the header. 
            ((FileStream)br.BaseStream).Seek(header.headerLen, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Read in all the records
            for (int counter = 0; counter <= header.numRecords - 1; counter++)
            {
                // First we'll read the entire record into a buffer and then read each field from the buffer
                // This helps account for any extra space at the end of each record and probably performs better
                buffer = br.ReadBytes(header.recordLen);
                recReader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(buffer));

                // All dbf field records begin with a deleted flag field. Deleted - 0x2A (asterisk) else 0x20 (space)
                if (recReader.ReadChar() == '*')
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Loop through each field in a record
                fieldIndex = 0;
                row = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (FieldDescriptor field in fields)
                {
                    switch (field.fieldType)
                    {
                        case 'N':  // Number
                            // If you port this to .NET 2.0, use the Decimal.TryParse method
                            number = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recReader.ReadBytes(field.fieldLen));

                            if (IsNumber(number))
                            {
                                if (number.IndexOf(".") > -1)
                                {
                                    //row[fieldIndex] = decimal.Parse(number);
                                    row[fieldIndex] = GetDoubleFromString(number);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    row[fieldIndex] = GetDoubleFromString(number);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row[fieldIndex] = 0;
                            }

                            break;

                        case 'C': // String
                            //number = ConvertString(number, Encoding.GetEncoding(866), Encoding.Default);
                            //string value =recReader.ReadBytes(field.fieldLen).ToString();
                            //row[fieldIndex] = recReader.ReadBytes(field.fieldLen).ToString();
                            //byte[] tmp = recReader.ReadBytes(field.fieldLen);
                            //string temp1 = ConvertString(tmp, Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.Default);
                            //temp1 = ConvertString(tmp, Encoding.GetEncoding(866), Encoding.Default);
                            //temp1 = ConvertString(tmp, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), Encoding.Default);
                            //temp1 = ConvertString(tmp, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
                            //temp1 = ConvertString(tmp, Encoding.GetEncoding(866), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
                            //temp1 = ConvertString(tmp, Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
                            //temp1 = ConvertString(tmp, Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
                            row[fieldIndex] = ConvertString(recReader.ReadBytes(field.fieldLen), Encoding.GetEncoding(866), Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
                            //row[fieldIndex] = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(866), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), recReader.ReadBytes(field.fieldLen));


                            break;

                        case 'D': // Date (YYYYMMDD)
                            year = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recReader.ReadBytes(4));
                            month = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recReader.ReadBytes(2));
                            day = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recReader.ReadBytes(2));
                            row[fieldIndex] = System.DBNull.Value;
                            try
                            {
                                if (IsNumber(year) && IsNumber(month) && IsNumber(day))
                                {
                                    if ((Int32.Parse(year) > 1900))
                                    {
                                        row[fieldIndex] = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(year), Int32.Parse(month), Int32.Parse(day));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            { }

                            break;

                        case 'T': // Timestamp, 8 bytes - two integers, first for date, second for time
                            // Date is the number of days since 01/01/4713 BC (Julian Days)
                            // Time is hours * 3600000L + minutes * 60000L + Seconds * 1000L (Milliseconds since midnight)
                            lDate = recReader.ReadInt32();
                            lTime = recReader.ReadInt32() * 10000L;
                            row[fieldIndex] = JulianToDateTime(lDate).AddTicks(lTime);
                            break;

                        case 'L': // Boolean (Y/N)
                            if ('Y' == recReader.ReadByte())
                            {
                                row[fieldIndex] = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row[fieldIndex] = false;
                            }

                            break;

                        case 'F':
                            number = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recReader.ReadBytes(field.fieldLen));
                            if (IsNumber(number))
                            {
                                //row[fieldIndex] = double.Parse(number);
                                row[fieldIndex] = GetDoubleFromString(number);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //row[fieldIndex] = 0.0F;
                                row[fieldIndex] = GetDoubleFromString(number);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    fieldIndex++;
                }

                recReader.Close();
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            //throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != br)
            {
                br.Close();
            }
        }

        long count = DateTime.Now.Ticks - start;

        return dt;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Simple function to test is a string can be parsed. There may be a better way, but this works
    /// If you port this to .NET 2.0, use the new TryParse methods instead of this
    ///   *Thanks to wu.qingman on code project for fixing a bug in this for me
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number">string to test for parsing</param>
    /// <returns>true if string can be parsed</returns>
    #region GetDoubleFromString(String aStr)

    private static Double GetDoubleFromString(String aStr)
    {
        // Подготавливаем строку
        aStr = aStr.Trim(new char[] { '(', ')', ' ' });

        // Временная переменная
        Double tmpd = 0;

        // Получаем текущие настройки
        var format = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();

        // Пытаемся преобразовать строку в число
        if (!Double.TryParse(aStr, NumberStyles.Float, format, out tmpd))
        {
            if (format.NumberDecimalSeparator == ",")
                format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            else if (format.NumberDecimalSeparator == ".")
                format.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
            // Если всеравно не удалось то возвращаем -1
            if (!Double.TryParse(aStr, NumberStyles.Float, format, out tmpd))
                return -1;
        }
        return tmpd;
    }
    #endregion

    public static bool IsNumber(string numberString)
    {
        char[] numbers = numberString.ToCharArray();
        int number_count = 0;
        int point_count = 0;
        int space_count = 0;

        foreach (char number in numbers)
        {
            if ((number >= 48 && number <= 57))
            {
                number_count += 1;
            }
            else if (number == 46)
            {
                point_count += 1;
            }
            else if (number == 32)
            {
                space_count += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return (number_count > 0 && point_count < 2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a Julian Date to a .NET DateTime structure
    /// Implemented from pseudo code at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lJDN">Julian Date to convert (days since 01/01/4713 BC)</param>
    /// <returns>DateTime</returns>
    private static DateTime JulianToDateTime(long lJDN)
    {
        double p = Convert.ToDouble(lJDN);
        double s1 = p + 68569;
        double n = Math.Floor(4 * s1 / 146097);
        double s2 = s1 - Math.Floor((146097 * n + 3) / 4);
        double i = Math.Floor(4000 * (s2 + 1) / 1461001);
        double s3 = s2 - Math.Floor(1461 * i / 4) + 31;
        double q = Math.Floor(80 * s3 / 2447);
        double d = s3 - Math.Floor(2447 * q / 80);
        double s4 = Math.Floor(q / 11);
        double m = q + 2 - 12 * s4;
        double j = 100 * (n - 49) + i + s4;
        return new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(j), Convert.ToInt32(m), Convert.ToInt32(d));
    }

}
```